# java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB Error while checking for permission

Tags: java, android

This stack size error occurs only in some devices.

```
public void configureLocation() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
       //Error occurs in the following line 
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 10);
        } else {
            requestLocationUpdate();
        }
    } else {
        requestLocationUpdate();
    }
}

java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.getDefault(ActivityManagerNative.java:97)
at android.app.ContextImpl.checkPermission(ContextImpl.java:1644)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.checkPermission(ContextWrapper.java:721)
at android.support.v4.content.b.a(ContextCompat.java:432)
at com.kawasolutions.Kawa.d.a.d.R(MainFragment.java:326)
at com.kawasolutions.Kawa.d.a.d.a(MainFragment.java:569)
```

Function 'configureLocation' is only called once in the activity.

Comment: `error occurs only in some devices.` which devices?

Comment: till now.. i have found this issue with  - Huawei Nexus 6p - Samsung SM N920T and Samsung SM-G935F

Comment: do you have some big data in bundles?

Comment: No.. I haven't used any bundles in this activity. But i have an arraylist of customClass 'Drivers' which consist of driverdetails that is updated from server every 15 seconds. Can this cause this issue?

Comment: also getting the trace on Samsung  SM-N920V

Comment: Did you got the solution for your issue? As I am also facing the same issue.